# Interpolation technique used in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

What is the technique used by the `numpy` `interp()` function?

So using the following points

```
import numpy as np

x = [4.5]
xp = [4, 5, 4, 3]
yp = [2, 4, 6, 5]

result = np.interp(x, xp, yp)

print(result) #result = 5.0
```

When I find the interpolation of `x` the value is `4.5`

But if my points are these 3 `xp = [4, 5, 4]` e `yp = [2, 4, 6]` the value will be `6`

```
import numpy as np

x = [4.5]
xp = [4, 5, 4]
yp = [2, 4, 6]

result = np.interp(x, xp, yp)

print(result) #result = 6.0
```

Comment: Why are the xp` values duplicated and not sorted?  Read the warnings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function np.interp linkes the given points two by two, so it can build a total of (number_of_given_points_in_xp - 1) linear function and constant outside the min and max of xp. and xp usually should be sorted and does not have duplicates. \

In your case it will create 3 linear functions. But you are using value 4 two time which makes the function outputting illogical values:

Here is a typical implementation of the function

```
xp = [1, 2, 3]
fp = [3, 7, 0]
p=[-2, -1, 1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.7, 4] # values to predict and then to plot
plt.plot(p, np.interp(p, xp, fp))
plt.scatter(xp, fp, c='red')
plt.show()
```

here is the output of my code:

[image]

In your case;

```
xp = [4, 5, 4, 3]
fp = [2, 4, 6, 5]
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3.5, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5], np.interp([0, 1, 2, 3.5, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5], xp, fp))
plt.scatter(xp, fp, c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your input the values in `xp` are not in ascending order, so for this example the question is moot. Check out the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

> xp: 1-D sequence of floats
>
> The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing (...)